# How to get "genericInfo" from method in java reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I have class, DummyController,

```
@APSController
@RequestMapping("grand/old/dummy")
public class DummyContollerV2 {

    private final EntityResponseWrapper<Dummy> wrapper = EntityResponseWrapper.buildForEntity(Dummy.class);

    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public HttpEntity<DendriteEnvelope<Dummy>> createNewDummy(
            @RequestBody final Dummy newDummy) {

        newDummy.setId("3");
        newDummy.setApproved(false);
        newDummy.setValue(ValuesEnum.VALUE_2);
        return wrapper.wrapEntityResult(() -> newDummy);
    }
}
```

What I want is tree of the return type, and its generics, of the "createNewDummy" method.

I have found, through debugging, that I can call the method:

```
    Class controllerClass = DummyContollerV2.class;
    List<Method> methods = Arrays.asList(controllerClass.getMethods());
    ClassTypeSignature returnSigniture = methods.get(0).getGenericInfo().getTree().getReturnType();
```

Where the "returnSignature" let's me traverse each class and the "ClassTypeSignature" of its generic types. However, the "getGernicInfo" method is private, and can only be accessed through debugging (or hacking with more reflection).

It shows that the generic information of the return class is reserved at run time. Does anyone know how I can access this information?

I know this question is probably a duplicate, but I wasn't able to find a question that addressed this exactly.

Comment: Not sure if this will help but we found this blog post to be very useful to get generic info on a class level (this should at least be partially applicable on method return types): http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=208860

Comment: Thanks. Trying to work through it now. It's promising.

Comment: In this case, you don't need to use the stuff discussed in that blog post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you can use [`getGenericReturnType`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getGenericReturnType()), because the generic return type is present in the class file:

```
Type t = methods.get(0).getGenericReturnType();
```

You can get the relevant classes using something like the following:

```
ParameterizedType genericHttpEntity = (ParameterizedType) t;

Class<?> httpEntity = (Class<?>) genericHttpEntity.getRawType();

ParameterizedType genericDendriteEnvelope =
    (ParameterizedType) genericHttpEntity.getActualTypeArguments()[0];

Class<?> dendriteEnvelope = (Class<?>) genericDendriteEnvelope.getRawType();

Class<?> dummy = (Class<?>) genericDendriteEnvelope.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
```

There isn't any API for traversing instances of [`java.lang.reflect.Type`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Type.html) like a tree, but you could write one. You need to handle the types listed by the JavaDoc as its subtypes.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a 4 year old question but to answer the original one, to access the generic info, the following would be helpful:

```
Method getGenericInfoMethod = Class.class.getDeclaredMethod("getGenericInfo");
genericInfo.setAccessible(true);
Object info = getGenericInfoMethod.invoke(clazz);
if (info != null) {
      Method treeMethod = info.getClass().getMethod("getTree");
      Object tree = treeMethod.invoke(info);
}
genericInfo.setAccessible(false);
```

The getGenericInfo method is accessible from Class via reflection. Probably works only for jdk 11.